# Selecting a specific row with a desired value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to get a row if it has the desired specific value, otherwise get the first or default:

```
dr =
   (from avTable in DAL.DataStore.DSet.Tables["Values1"].AsEnumerable()
    join pavTable in DAL.DataStore.DSet.Tables["Values2"].AsEnumerable()
        on avTable.Field<int>("PK") equals pavTable.Field<int>("FK_Value")
    where 
          pavTable.Field<int>("FKI_ProductAttribute") == Value2 &&
          avTable.Field<string>("Name") == "Specific Value"
    select avTable).FirstOrDefault() ??
    (from avTable in DAL.DataStore.DSet.Tables["Values1"].AsEnumerable()
     join pavTable in DAL.DataStore.DSet.Tables["Values2"].AsEnumerable()
     on avTable.Field<int>("PK") equals pavTable.Field<int>("FK_Value")
     where pavTable.Field<int>("FKI_ProductAttribute") == Value2
     select avTable).FirstOrDefault();
```

This smells. Is there a better way to do this?

I want to do something like this:

```
var dt =
   (from avTable in DAL.DataStore.DSet.Tables["Values1"].AsEnumerable()
    join pavTable in DAL.DataStore.DSet.Tables["Values2"].AsEnumerable()
        on avTable.Field<int>("PK") equals pavTable.Field<int>("FK_Value")
    where 
          pavTable.Field<int>("FKI_ProductAttribute") == Value2 &&
          avTable.Field<string>("Name") == "Specific Value"
    select avTable)

DataRow dr = dt.Select("PK = Specified value");
If(dr==null) dr = dt.FirstOrDefault();
```

and then do a select based on a specified value. If that is `null`, then grab the first or default. This seems to be more DRY, but is it more or less efficient?. Also, I have a hard time doing a select on the dt based on the specific value (lack of Linq expertise and Google prowess to find the answer I am looking for).

Comment: This is the way `FirstOrDefault` is supposed to work ...? I don't see anything that 'smells' ...unless there is some optimization to the query. But nothing I can really see ...

Comment: It just doesn't seem DRY to me, so I clarified what I am looking to do.

Comment: *'But nothing I can really see ...'* ...and then I put my glasses on ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work?

```
var dr= (from avTable in DAL.DataStore.DSet.Tables["Values1"].AsEnumerable()
         join pavTable in DAL.DataStore.DSet.Tables["Values2"].AsEnumerable()
             on avTable.Field<int>("PK") equals pavTable.Field<int>("FK_Value");
         where
             (pavTable.Field<int>("FKI_ProductAttribute") == Value2 &&
              avTable.Field<string>("Name") == "Specific Value") ||
              pavTable.Field<int>("FKI_ProductAttribute") == Value2
         select avTable)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't really have a way to test this, but I believe if the first part of the `where` clause criteria is met, the part after the `||` is skipped. If the first part returns no record then the second part is evaluated and will return a result ...or null.